# Create and call Variables In a for loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, tkinter

i am trying to make it so that a user inputs a number, and that number of buttons are created Using TKinter, I have tried doing it by using the following, Where the Buttons are successfully created, however i am struggling with calling them in order to  place them / display them on the grid (Added randint to simulate user input (User Input not limited to 9 and may be as high as 40))

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
inputValue = randint(3,9)
print(inputValue)
root = Tk()
while inputValue > 0: # for every number in inputted value
    inputValue = int(inputValue) - 1 # take one
    globals()['Sailor%s' % inputValue] = Button(root, text="Lap :" + str(inputValue), command=lambda: retrieve_input())  # Create the button function in the format 'Sailors{Inputnumber}'
    ('Sailors%s' % inputValue).grid(row=inputValue, column=1, columnspan=2)  # Place the button (Doesn't work)
root.mainloop()  # Does work (required)
```

Howerver the following does not work (It is meant to place the button),

```
('Sailors%s' % inputValue).grid(row=inputValue, column=1, columnspan=2)  # Place the button (Doesn't work)
```

Can you think of a method i can use in order to create and place  Amount of buttons? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer pointed out that you'd have to use the `globals` dictionary to do this. But that raises the question: why in the world are you not just using a `dict` or any other container to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never create dynamic variable names like you are attempting to do. It adds a lot of complexity, reduces clarity, and provides no real benefit.

Instead, use a dictionary or list to keep track of the buttons. In your case, however, since you're never using the buttons anywhere but in the loop you can just use a local variable.

Example using a local variable, in case you never need to access the button in code after you create it:

```
for count in range(inputValue):
    button = Button(...)
    button.grid(...)
```

Here's how you do it if you need to access the buttons later in your code:

```
buttons = []
for count in range(inputValue):
    button = Button(...)
    button.grid(...)
    buttons.append(button)
```

With the above you can iterate over all of the buttons in `buttons`:

```
for button in buttons:
    button.configure(state='disabled')
```

If you need to configure a single button, use its index:

```
button[0].configure(...)
```

Comment: This only creates one button when i try to do it?

Comment: @ItzKmaf: no, it creates as many buttons as the number you specify. I literally just replaced `globals()['Sailor%s' % inputValue]` with `button` in your code and when I ran it I got 6 buttons.

Comment: my mistake, Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can calling grid on a string at the moment, which throws your error.

Your need to replace `('Sailors%s' % inputValue)` with `globals()['Sailor%s' % inputValue]`, with orders your buttons on individual rows, labeled 0-8.

So, your current code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
inputValue = randint(3,9)
print(inputValue)
root = Tk()
while inputValue > 0: # for every number in inputted value
    inputValue = int(inputValue) - 1 # take one
    globals()['Sailor%s' % inputValue] = Button(root, text="Lap :" + str(inputValue), command=lambda: retrieve_input())  # Create the button function in the format 'Sailors{Inputnumber}'
    globals()['Sailor%s' % inputValue].grid(row=inputValue, column=1, columnspan=2)  
root.mainloop()  # Does work (required)
```

When `retrieve_input` is defined, the code will work fine.

Just to point out, instead of `inputValue = int(inputValue) - 1` you can use `inputValue -= 1`.

Comment: Thanks... I used the 'int(inputValue)' because the input from the user is in str format and it seemed more efficient to do it that way than 'inputValue=int(inputValue)'
'inputValue -= 1'